# How can I build an application on a build server by not having all my DLLs in the same repository as the application

Tags: c#, git, dll, msbuild, teamcity

I'm trying to set up a build and deployment pipeline, however there are a number of dlls required by the project which I can't put into the same git repository as the application, so when I check-in, these 4 dlls don't go into source control (by design).

What I am trying to achieve is the ability to share a repository without the dlls which come as part of a licensed package, but still be able to build and deploy my application using TeamCity. Is it possible to have these four dlls in a separate repository, but to be able to pull them as part of the build process in TeamCity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a separate VCS-Root for the shared dlls and attach to your build. To put the dlls in the desired folder you can define check-out rules while attaching the VCS.

Comment: I've added a VCS root to my build config, with the repo containing the DLls, and created a checkout rule on the new VCS root of '+:VCSPath=> %teamcity.build.workingDir%/lib' as the build is expecting the dlls in a lib folder alongside the solution file however, the build still failed. On checking the build agent directory it seems the dlls haven't been deployed to the Lib folder...

Comment: Did you check in the build logs where the checkout rule path is resolving to. Also try without the working dir param, I think teamcity itself works from the working directory.

Comment: it doesn't make it explicit just `[09:56:58]Building incremental patch for VCS root: DLLs; checkout rules: VCSPath=>lib; revision: 3286e5463971f06b24f6de71cf8fcb7a74c040c2 --> 3286e5463971f06b24f6de71cf8fcb7a74c040c2`

Comment: Hang on a sec, are you using VCSPath=>lib. Well VCSPath means the directory in your source which you are checking out. See http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Checkout+Rules

Comment: Ah,Awesome, I changed vcspath to '.' its working now. Thanks!